# How to call GET api with query params having special chars{&,(,),'} using spring rest template

Tags: java, urlencode, spring-resttemplate

Below was the code used to encode uri having query params using `UriComponentsBuilder`

```
String uri = "http://hostname/api/items"
// api expected with params --> http://hostname/api/items?filter=IN('123') and id eq '123_&123'
restTemplate.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).queryParam("filter","IN('123') and id eq '123_&123'").encode().toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, request, Response_Entity.class)
```

When above code is called, somehow at api side, i was getting 2 query params with keys -->`filter` & `123`

How to handle it correctly using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow query params are encoded and at api side, by default these are retrieved correctly after decoding, if i use `toURI()` of `UriComponentsBuilder`

Same was not working if i convert it to string using `toUriString`

Below is the code which worked for me.

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri)
                              .queryParam("filter",encodedParam)
                              .encode()
                              .build()
                              .toUri();

restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response_Entity.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

try encoding query param by using URLEncoder.

```
String param = "IN('123') and id eq '123_&123'";
String encodedParam = URLEncoder.encode(param, Charset.defaultCharset()));    
restTemplate.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).queryParam("filter",encodedParam).toUriString(), httpMethod, httpEntity, Some_Entity.class)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding